# placeholder change data

Tags: php, contentplaceholder

I have a form which gets user's telephone and stores it in an database. Then I am fetching data from the database and place it on placeholder like this.

```
Telephone<input name="telephone" type="text" size="25" placeholder="<?php echo $user_data_profile['telephone']; ?>"/>
```

everything is fine. I want to make the placeholder's data to appear as an editable text, so that the user will have the option to change his telephone number easy. Any suggestions?

Comment: Put it in `value=""` instead? It doesn't make a lot of sense in `placeholder`, that's usually prompt-level information like `xxx-xxx-xxxx`.

Comment: I did it and works. The only problem now is that if the user delete the all text and press save, keeps the previous value.

Comment: That's a problem with your server-side script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
Telephone
<input name="telephone" type="text" size="25"
       placeholder="xxx-xxx-xxxx" value="<?=$user_data_profile['telephone']?>"/>
```

Using whatever phone number format that is relative to your area.